# how to update the previous page from the current page child stateless widget after Navigator.pushNamed()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page (stateful widget) that loads a child widget, this child widget is a grid, and it's loads another child widget a single grid item details.

on single grid item details, there is InkWell, and when onTap I Navigate to a new page.

the grid widget and the single grid item are both stateless widgets

when I go back from the new page using the back button I would like to update the previews page.

for example from the single grid item i have:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
          context,
          SingleMoviePage.routeName,
          arguments: movie,
        ).then((_){
          var pressed = Provider.of<MoviesListProvider>(context,listen: false).listPageButtonPressed;
          if (pressed) {
            updateChanges();
          }
        });
```

I can update the page by passing the updateChanges function to grid widget and from the grid widget to the page.
but is there a better way to do it using provider ? or another way without the need to send the function from child to parent and from the parent to the grandparent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can do so by putting your data source in a `ChangeNotifier` and when it's updated you can `notify` all widgets that depend on it.

Another fast solution is to access  the statful widget's state using a `GlobalKey` like this:

```
GlobalKey<yourStateFulWidget> myKey = GlobalKey()
```

and then access and edite the data like:

```
 myKey.currentState!.someFunctionOrData();
```

note: to get a better understanding on how to do the first solution I recommend you to read the official example by the flutter team here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: thanks, I put the data source in a ChangeNotifier and this is working great, I wanted to try also the GlobalKey but I was not able to make it work, my task is to update a previous page from the child widget of the current page after Navigation pop